# Issue when create new user in admin using Rails_admin gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am developing Rails application where used `rails_admin gem`. But when I tried to `create new user` at that time `password field not display` in admin and Not able to create new user.

I got below error:

```
undefined method `new' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Sections::Base:0x000000088d5d08>
```

Anyone have a idea or experience in it. Where I am  missing or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change `new` to `edit`: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#form-rendering. Both methods use the same partial and/or rendering logic.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `edit` section. You can check the action name in this way

```
edit do
  include_all_fields
  fields :attr_1, :attr_2 do
    visible do
      bindings[:controller].action_name == 'new'
    end
  end
end
```